# formula for copying verticle matrix of 2x2 into horizontal format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am looking for a formula that copies 4 cells from vertical to horizontal. and if I change the data in the vertical section it changes automatically in the horizontal section. here is an example. I have tried using offset function but was unsuccessful. Please advice.

```
     A   B  C  D  E  F  G  H   I
  -------------------------------
1 |            1  3  5  6  a1  a2
2 |            2  4  7  8  a3  a4
3 |
4 |  1   3   
5 |  2   4
6 |  5   6
7 |  7   8
8 |  a1  a2    
9 |  a3  a4
```

======================

1. Let me explain the problem. Let’s says I have a data in the following the fields:

A1   B1

A2   B2

A3   B3      C3    D3

A4   B4      C4    D4

A5   B5      C5    D5

A6   B6      C6    D6

```
              C7     D7
              C8     D8
```

2. I would like to reference this data into other field , let’s say in:

E1    F1    G1    H1   I1   J 1   …

E2    F2    G2    H2   I2   J 2    …

```
             G3    H3   I3    J3    K3    L3    M3    …

            G4     H4   I4    J4    K4    L4    M4    …
```

3.The pattern of the reference should follow a pattern (reference 2x2 cells and move down the next group of cells) which is as followed:

E1=A1      F1=B1     G1=A3      H1= B3     I1=A5    J 1=B5

E2=A2     F2=B2      G2=A4       H2=B4      I2=A6    J 2=B6

```
                              G3=C3      H3= D3     I3=C5    J 3=D5     L3=C7     M3=D7 ….

                             G4=C4       H4= D4     I4=C6    J4=D6      L4 =C8    M4=D8 ….
```

Note, it needs to be applies on a larger scale of cells.

Comment: Your question is confusing. What exactly you've tried and why that doesn't work?  Will your range change, or will you be always interested in the same cells?

Answer (score 2):

All you need is the `TRANSPOSE` function.

Select cells D1:I2 and put `=TRANSPOSE(A4:B9)` in the formula bar and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to validate it as an array formula.